# anchor build can not execute why anchor init works

Tags: ubuntu, anchor, rust-cargo, solana, anchor-solana

I am new to solana and linux os, i am following a tutorial on anchor development. my issues is that when i run anchor init in my terminal it works well and generate necessary things for the project, but when i run anchor build this error is thrown "error: not a file: '/home/austinedavid/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.17.16/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/rust/bin/rustc'".

I tried to run anchor build which is supposed to build the program for necessary testing and deploying